# Comparing string with with quotation against string without quotation

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code comparing two values like this:

`If .Cells(c, 1).Value = TaskOnWP_lst.List(x, 0) Then`

Resulting in:

`If 442228 = "442228`

which returns `false` but should be `true`.

My problem is that the "cells value" is without quotation marks and the `taskonwplist` value is With quotation marks.

Can anyone please help me With this

Henning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
If .Cells(c, 1).Value = Replace(TaskOnWP_lst.List(x, 0),"""","")
```

Which would replace `"` with nothing.